# 3rd party videos in iOS app, legal issue?

Tags: ios, ios-appstore, copyright

If I were to make an iOS app that whichs primary function is to play specific 3rd party YouTube videos, is that okay to do without asking for their permission? Or do I need to have a legal agreement with each publisher?

Comment: Please keep in mind that you won't get legal advice here. Depending of the nature and scope of your application you may be better off consulting a lawyer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting in youtube called public.

That means anyone can view it, including downloading or from other apps ect.

If the owner wants to prevent that he/she can do that in youtube settings.

As long your app is not breaking the youtube T&Cs and you are fine.

Consider following: many websites contain link to youtube and many even allow embedding the videos, so it is up to the owner to allow or not.